# Queuing .Net Core SignalR invoke request

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, websocket, signalr

When a user makes an invoke request, another user should not enter that method until the operations are completed. When you wait in the queue and the process is finished, the other request should be processed.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The question is subject to differing opinions, which is not what SO is for. Try some implementation, post code, ask questions generally is what you want to do.

That said and given the brief description, I don't think you are going to be able to stop your clients from invoking a method without issues. You could use ConcurrentQueue to collect your invoke calls and process them in the order they are added to the queue.

Here is a documentation reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-5.0